# Why does the stress of fluid depend on rate of deformation unlike stress of solid that depends on deformation itself?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

[image]

***So as stated in the picture above, stress behavior in fluids and solids isn't the same. Why is it physically that way?***

Comment: Some materials are bonded strongly enough to not settle into the shape of their container (solids), and some materials aren’t (fluids). Does this get at what you’re asking about?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I'm more concerned about the relation between stress and deformation. For fluid, stress is as a function of rate of deformation whereas for solid its directly related to deformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's address a possible misconception: that if we switch from a solid to a fluid, the stress $\tau$ switches from being dependent on the deformation (only) to being dependent on the deformation rate (only). This is not correct.

Solids resist deformation **and** flow (deformation rate) **and** acceleration (rate of deformation rate) and so on. Consider ice, for example: Its shear modulus $G$, which quantifies its resistance to shear deformation $\gamma$, is several gigapascals. Its resistance to flow can be obtained from a deformation mechanism map:

[image]

Here, we can obtain the shear stress needed at any particular temperature to achieve a certain flow rate; this quantifies ice's viscosity $\mu$ or resistance to a shear deformation rate $\dot\gamma$.

In turn, ice's resistance to a time rate of change in its deformation rate ($\ddot\gamma$) is related to its density.

The point I'm making is that resistance generally exists for deformation **and all of its time derivatives**. You may have heard that the stress depends on the deformation (only), but this is a simplification.

Now, when we call something a fluid, we mean that it's bonded weakly enough that it rearranges quickly and nearly effortlessly under any load. Thus, we take its shear modulus—its resistance to shear $\gamma$—as zero. But the resistance to the time derivatives of the deformation remain. For further idealization, if the resistance to flow $\dot\gamma$ is negligible to us, then we might consider the fluid to be **[inviscid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow)**. But the resistance to acceleration $\ddot\gamma$ remains—the fluid isn't massless.

I hope this clarifies why it would inaccurate to say that stress in a solid and fluid depends (only) on the deformation and deformation rate, respectively. That's what simple models such as $\tau=G\gamma$ and $\tau=\mu\dot\gamma$ might imply, but that's only because these models are considering only static deformation and steady flow, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Nonhydrostatic stresses are transmitted in liquids via shear forces which only exist when the fluid has viscosity and possesses velocity gradients. In this case, more motion means more stress. An example of this is the flow of fluid over a stationary surface, where shear stresses are transmitted from the fluid to the wall.